# javascript and iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, popup

In my website I use an iframe to show an external content but there is a popup window in it.
I can/do block popups in my site but not inside the iframe, is there a way to disable a specific (or all) javascript from an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Internet Explorer specific](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534622%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) way to disable scripts in a frame, but nothing general.

You really should negotiate with the owner of the document that you are reusing.